# Selenium docker crashes on Windows (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Summary: works on the mac but not on windows. Please note: This is not a duplicate of other similar issues, I have researched this for more than a day on SO and elsewhere.

I built a super simple script which executes 2 dockers containers: one with chrome browser, chromedriver and the other with the test. It runs fine on Linux, but when I launch the containers on Windows I'm getting;

```
root@4ba2401510ed:/wdir# ../usr/bin/php7.1 chromeTest.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownErrorException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has 
crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '5cc73cb1d7df', ip: '172.18.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2', java.version: '1.8.0_282'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: #0 0x564b66a6ce89 <unknown>
 in /wdir/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php:139
Stack trace:
#0 /wdir/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php(371): Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException::throwException('unknown error', 'unknown error: ...', Array)
#1 /wdir/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php(135): Facebook\WebDriver\Rem in /wdir/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php on line 139
```

Has anyone seen this before? It looks like Docker just behaves differently on Windows and makes the Chrome inside the docker container crash..

I tried proposed solutions such as adding `--headless`, `--sandbox`, etc. but it really seems to be something with the way docker works on windows.

### Yaml file

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  # Contains the chrome browser, chromedriver
  chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
      - "5900:5900"

  # Contains PHP webdriver library
  php7:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/wdir/
    depends_on:
      - chrome
    command: tail -F anything
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM scratch
ADD ubuntu-xenial-core-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz /
ADD start.sh /
# Chromium DEB file
#ADD google-chrome-stable_90.0.4430.85-1_amd64.deb /
#ADD chromedriver /
# ADD firefox_88.0-1_i386.deb /

# a few minor docker-specific tweaks
# see https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap
RUN set -xe \
  \
# https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L40-L48
  && echo '#!/bin/sh' > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d \
  && echo 'exit 101' >> /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d \
  && chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d \
  \
# https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L54-L56
  && dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl \
  && cp -a /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d /sbin/initctl \
  && sed -i 's/^exit.*/exit 0/' /sbin/initctl \
  \
# https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L71-L78
  && echo 'force-unsafe-io' > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/docker-apt-speedup \
  \
# https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L85-L105
  && echo 'DPkg::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean \
  && echo 'APT::Update::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean \
  && echo 'Dir::Cache::pkgcache ""; Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache "";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean \
  \
# https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L109-L115
  && echo 'Acquire::Languages "none";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-no-languages \
  \
# https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L118-L130
  && echo 'Acquire::GzipIndexes "true"; Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order:: "gz";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-gzip-indexes \
  \
# https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L134-L151
  && echo 'Apt::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant "false";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-autoremove-suggests

# this forces "apt-get update" in dependent images, which is also good
# (see also https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1699913)

# make systemd-detect-virt return "docker"
# See: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/aa0c34279ee40bce2f9681b496922dedbadfca19/src/basic/virt.c#L434
RUN mkdir -p /run/systemd && echo 'docker' > /run/systemd/container

# Install updates
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y software-properties-common language-pack-en-base \
\
# Install Java
-y default-jre \
\
# Install snapd
-y snapd \
\ 
# Install wget
-y wget \
-y lsof

# Clean up
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Get the PHP library
RUN LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y \
    php7.1 \
    php7.1-pgsql \
    php-pear \
    php7.1-curl \
    php7.1-sqlite3 \
    php7.1-xml \
    php7.1-bcmath \
    php7.1-zip \
    php7.1-mbstring \
    php-xdebug \
    php7.1-mysqli \
    php-ast


# Define the working directory for this container
WORKDIR /wdir

# RUN chmod +x ./start.sh

CMD ["start.sh"]
```

Comment: did you rebuild it with --no-cache option? also needs to see the docker file

Comment: @mahen3d thank you for the reply, yes, unfortunately it didn't help. Attaching the yaml and the dockerfiles. Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: try different image and see "selenium/standalone-chrome"

Comment: @mahen3d interesting... i'm actually getting a different error now, I think i'll try a few more version but it could be as simple as downgrading the whole node a little bit. Thank you, I'll keep testing on my end.

Comment: @mahen3d you were right it's some sort of an incompatibility issue that occured after latest windows update, rolling back to a previous version fixed it. Can you post it as the answer and i'll accept

Comment: Thanks i have posted an answer, feel free to edit it, add more information ..etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be due to issues occurred when a windows update and docker image not updated accordingly. Try rolling back to a previous version can fix it.

Further, try experimenting with different docker images like

```
"selenium/standalone-chrome"
```

will help to debug the issue.

Example of a previous image which worked before the windows WSL update

```
image: selenium/standalone-chrome:89.0.4389.90-chromedriver-89.0.4389.23-20210315
```

Some options may need to be tweaked also while instantiating the driver object, here's a working example

```
$options = new ChromeOptions();
$options->addArguments(["no-sandbox","headless", "disable-dev-shm-usage"]);
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
$capabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY_W3C, $options);
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities);
```

Comment: bingo! I rolled back to an earlier version and problem was solved.. I edited your answer with more details.

Comment: Running in headless mode fixes it for me, but I need to download files and file downloads are not currently supported in headless mode, for security reasons. Bit of a pain :(